# Fill Each Square With A Random Color

Tags: java, random, stddraw

I am trying to fill the whole screen with squares, each one filled with a different color. I am able to generate the entire screen full of squares, but I cannot get them to be a random color. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RGBRandom
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
{
StdDraw.setScale(0, 100);

for (int x = 0; x <= 100; x++)
{     
  for (int y = 0; y <= 100; y++)
  {
    int r = (int)Math.random()*256;

    int g = (int)Math.random()*256;

    int b = (int)Math.random()*256;

    StdDraw.setPenColor(r, g, b);
    StdDraw.filledSquare(x, y, 0.5);
  }
} 
}
}
```

Comment: Do they all have the same color or do you have duplicate colors?

Comment: @inda1 post your entire code

Answer (score 5):

The expression `Math.random()` generates a real number between 0 and 1 (not including 1). Your cast to an `(int)` effectively converts it to `0`. You need brackets around the whole expression so that the cast to an `int` comes after you have multiplied the random number by `256`.

E.g.

```
int r = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
```

Or, as Nichar suggests, use `Random` instead:

```
Random random = new Random();

...

int r = random.nextInt(256);
int g = random.nextInt(256);
int b = random.nextInt(256);
```

The `random.nextInt(256)` will give you a random number between 0 and 255 (inclusive). It would be better to create the instance of `Random` outside of the loops.

Answer (score 1):

Better use `nextInt()`, so it would look like this:

```
int randomNum = rand.nextInt(255)+1;
```

Comment: Upvoted and I've included your suggestion in my answer.